# How to model a target class for receiving a JSON html response in .NET5

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest, json-deserialization, blazor-webassembly, asp.net5

I'm trying to read a list of objects from a public WEB Api that provides a JSON file with an array of objects, I'm using Blazor and the **Net 5** platform.

The de-serialization fails with this error:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to Meme[].
```

**I suspect I'm modeling the "receiving" object incorrectly, should I change my code or use other libraries for this code to succeed?**

The Api can be found at [this endpoint](https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes), I tried reading the response in these two ways:

```
var response = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Meme[]>("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes");
```

and

```
var httpResponse = await Http.GetAsync("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes");
var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Meme[]>();
```

the Meme class is declared as such:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }
public int Width { get; set; }
public int Height { get; set; }
public int BoxCount { get; set; }
```

and the response should contain this content:

```
"success": true,
"data": {
    "memes": [
        {
            "id": "181913649",
            "name": "Drake Hotline Bling",
            "url": "https://i.imgflip.com/30b1gx.jpg",
            "width": 1200,
            "height": 1200,
            "box_count": 2
        },
        {
            ...
        },
        ... ]
    }
```

These are the libraries I'm including:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response includes more than your Memes itself. The Meme array is within the object `data` and `memes`. Modell the entire response and you will be able to deserialize it. So you will need the following:

```cs
    public class Response
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Meme[] memes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meme
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public int box_count { get; set; }
    }

// Now you can use that like this:

var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Response>();
```

Note that there is a handy tool in VS that generated that for me. You can paste JSON as classes under `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes`. You can still use "normal" camel casing but you may have to instruct the serializer to do not match property names case-sensitive.